# Google Cloud Build - Not able to get file from other directory

Tags: docker, build, cloud, lighthouse

I am currently trying to export data from Google Lighthouse. By default the file is saved to /home/chrome/reports. When i try to save the file to the default directory /workspace/ i get the following error:

*Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/workspace/myfile.csv'
Runtime error encountered: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/workspace/myfile.csv'*

**Yalm**

```yaml
steps:
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
  args:
  - run
  - --rm
  - --name=lighthouse
  - -v=/workspace/:/home/chrome/reports
  - femtopixel/google-lighthouse
  - http://www.google.com
  - --output=json
  - --output-path=/workspace/myfile.json
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the directory /workspace does not exist where you want to export your file.

You could try creating the directory "workspace" in /

Comment: doesn't seem to be possible within the range of the args i can add in the yalm unfortunately.